# Javascript: even though I'm using window.onload I get the error 'var is not defined'

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a website with a button that goes to a next page and also calls a function in `main.js`, ignore the next page navigation for now.

What my HTML button code looks like:

```
<button onclick="resetAll()" id="beginButton" class="float-left submit-button"><h3>Begin</h3></button>
```

What my JS code looks like:

```
window.onload = function() {
  function resetAll() {
    // some resets and a log to show me it's been reset
    console.log("All reset");
  }
}
```

I expect the code to run through my js file until it finds the function 'resetAll()', but instead I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: resetAll is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`. I'd like to have this button link to the js file so my HTML doesn't get messed up with js code in there.

I've also tried to use the code

```
document.getElementById('beginButton').onclick = resetAll();
```

but that seems to run whenever the page get's loaded. As far as I know `window.onload` should make sure that the function is defined before the entire HTML page loads. My HTML script tag is in the head of my HTML code, so above the declaration of the button.

Can anyone help me out on this one? Because I keep getting stuck at issues like these..

Comment: Yes, remove it from window.onload -  and remove the `()` too: `document.getElementById('beginButton').onclick = resetAll;`

Comment: It is not defined because the function is not in global scope. It is in the scope of the block for `window.onload` so the button click event listener can not find it. The function should not be inside of the onload. You want to use the load event to trigger things when the page loads.  Now when you have `reset()` you are executing it and assigning what it returns to the event listener. It should just be `document.getElementById('beginButton').onclick = resetAll;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove it from window.onload (which has its own scope) -  and remove the `()` too: `document.getElementById('beginButton').onclick = resetAll;`

OR move the onclick inside:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('beginButton').onclick = function() {
    // some resets and a log to show me it's been reset
    console.log("All reset");
  }
}
```

Recommended

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById('beginButton').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // remove if you want the button to submit
  // some resets and a log to show me it's been reset
    console.log("All reset");
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using the same js code on different pages, but also adding .addEventListeners on different pages, meaning my entire js code won't work if I'm not on the first page. I'm using one js file because otherwise I need to figure out a way to make the variables global and usable in every js file. Do you have a way around this as well?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. You can do `var begin =  document.getElementById('beginButton'); if (begin) begin.addEventListener....`

Comment: I'm using the code you just submitted, but on index.html I've got a button to reset some stuff and also to `location.href = 'x.html'` but now on x.html I get the error that the variables I declared in `begin.addEventListener...` haven't been declared.  Also, on x.html I've got 2 clickable divs which give an error when not on that page. That's what I'm trying to get a workaround for

Comment: https://pastebin.com/uhBk1kmx that's all my js code --> I'm using the same variables on different pages which is what I'm mainly trying to accomplish. On the other hand the error I get now is that every `.onclick = function(event)` is not set if it's not on the current HTML page.

Comment: You need to move the vars outside the function. That is how a function works. vars defined inside a function is only available to the function. BUT regardless, when you then change the location ALL vars are cleared. You might want to use sessionStorage instead

Comment: you COULD ajax your HTML pages i, then the vars will stay

Comment: The reason I haven't moved the vars outside of the function is because every single page loads the same js file and thus rewrites the vars to their original state, instead of what the previous page changed them to. I think the best option here would be to use different js files and localStorage (is that the same as sessionStorage?), what do you think?

Comment: You can have one file but you cannot change location. You can NOT have the vars used by other functions if you have the var keyword inside the function. It will do nothing for the page vars. `beginButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      installeerPanelen = "false";
      verwarming = "";
      maandBedrag = 0;
      installatieKosten = 0;` will reset the vars if they are defined at the start of the page outside the functions. But then you load another page and then they are reset by the definition anyway at the page start

Comment: I understand the scope of the function and that I can't use the vars created inside outside of the function. I don't want the vars to reset at the load of each new page (with the same js file) which is why I don't want to declare them outside of the function. Best bet here?

Comment: 1. If you load a new page all vars are reset unless you get them from sessionStorage. I think that is what you want 2. If you AJAX the pages in, then nothing is reset

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to work with sessionStorage (or localStorage, what I found on another SO post)!

Answer (score 0):

You defined your resetAll function as local function, you cannot access it from out of onload function.

You should define like this

```
window.onload = function() {
  window.resetAll = function () {
    // some resets and a log to show me it's been reset
    console.log("All reset");
  }
}
```

and you assinged execution result of resetAll to onclick.

You should

```
document.getElementById('beginButton').onclick = resetAll
```

Comment: He can just move the function outside of the onload. It does not need to be there. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

I do not suggest using `element.onclick` syntax as others have suggested using. I also do not suggest inline events.

Instead, I suggest using the [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method.

```js
document.querySelector("#beginButton").addEventListener("click", e => {
   // resets and other code you want to happen when clicked 
   console.log("clicked!"); // just for the example
});
```

```html
<button id="beginButton" class="float-left submit-button"><h3>Begin</h3></button>
```

The reason your code doesn't work is that the function isn't created until the page loads so the inline function is undefined.

You don't need to wait for window onload if you put your JavaScript at the end if your `<body>` tag.